# Java NetBeans GUI design Vertical text align

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm making a Pascal triangle and I want vertical text align.

I output everything in Text Panel, I tried many options here but none seems to work. There are some align options in this editor but there are too many, I don't know which one will do what I want, can't find anything about that anywhere.

When it gets to double/triple digits it's not aligned vertically anymore. I'm making it from left to right, not in triangle shape.

Answer (score 0):

To vertically align text on adjacent lines, a fixed width [Font](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html) (such as `Courier`) can be used. If using `Swing`, you can can set the `Font` of a `JTextComponent` using the appropriate method:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
textArea.setFont(new Font("Courier", Font.PLAIN, 12));
```

If rendering with `html`, you can use the `<pre>` tag.

The fixed width Font will let the **n**th character on one line be aligned with the **n**th character on all other lines.